# Homogeneous Poisson Point Processes

Tags: r, plot, polygon, spatial, poisson

I'm plotting homogeneous spatial Poisson processes on various types of plots. I cannot figure out how to plot only on the upper right triangular area of the rectangular area. I added a polygon to the graph to define where I want to plot, but do not know how to restrict the points to all only plot on the top half of the rectangle.

```
N=50
u=runif(N,20,40)
v=runif(N,-10,10)
plot(u,v,asp=1)
polygon(c(0,0,55.5),c(-10,11.5,-10),col=NA,border='black')
```

Currently, I get this graph:
[image: plot]

How do I get all the points to the top triangle??

Comment: If you are willing to use a package this could easily be done using `spatstat` if I understand the question correctly.